# Basketball hoop on support pole in basement

Tags: basement, load-bearing, support, pole

I am wanting to install a medium sized basketball hoop into a support pole in the basement. Is it safe to drill into what I am assuming is a load bearing pole[image]. I attached photos of what it looked like during construction/now, and what I’m installing. Just making sure that it would not affect the structure. Thanks.

Comment: Just remember to get the upper screw above the metal plate to connects the post to the beam.

Comment: Hopefully nobody will be shooting threes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is not any unreasonable forces applied to the pole, ( Sumo sized players charging the net),  You should have no problems, since the support is anchored at both the top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

That's a wooden post. Screwing into it is fine.

A steel pole would be better clamped TO without drilling, on whole, though small holes *may* be tolerable. But that's not what you have.